# python3 AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'length'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I am trying to fix this AttributeError and been at it for a day and a half now. I am new to python trying to convert structured english code (pseudo code) to python 3 for a project.

```
Output: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 31, in <module>
    passwordVerifier(password)
  File "test.py", line 16, in passwordVerifier
    passwordArray = password.length()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'length'
```

```
#!/bin/python3
import os
import sys

import numpy

import office2john

def passwordVerifier(password):
    password = str(password)
    verifier = [numpy.uint16(1)] 
    passwordArray = [numpy.uint8(1)]
    verifier = 0x0000

    passwordArray = [0]
    passwordArray = bytes([])                           
    passwordArray = password.length()


    for password in passwordArray: 
        intermediate1 = 0 
        if password in passwordArray:
            intermediate1 = 1 
        else: 
            intermediate2 = verifier * 2 
            intermediate3 = intermediate1 
            verifier = intermediate3
        return verifier
```

Comment: `passwordArray = [0]`
`passwordArray = bytes([])`                           
`passwordArray = password.length()`
What do you hope to achieve here?

Comment: part of the pseudo code says ```SET PasswordArray TO (empty array of bytes) SET PasswordArray[0] TO Password.Length APPEND Password TO PasswordArray```

Comment: its confusing cause its like im writing the same variable multiple times.

Comment: Your title: "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit' " doesn't match your error code: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'length'

Answer (score 1):

`passwordArray = len(password)`

to check length of a string use `len`

so for `int`

`passwordArray = len(str(password))`

Comment: I just tried that now I am getting ```TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()```

Comment: use the lower one